# Writing documentation Contributing (automatic translation)

Tags: pytorch, translation, documentation, open-source, readme

I've attempted to translate a README document for an open-source project into different languages. However, I've been considering what would happen if there are changes made to the original document. In such cases, would I have to manually translate those changes into each translated document again? Or is there a possible solution to automate this process?

I'm not sure if it's possible to automatically translate the document, and I have concerns. Some languages, like Arabic, have different writing directions. When using an automatic translator, there's a chance that the order of words could get mixed up, especially if there are English terms in between. This could result in incorrect translations!!